# Excel condition with OR operator

Tags: excel

I am learning `MS Excel` formula making. If cell of column `A` has text `Sat` or `Sun` within then respective column `B` should be `Weekly Off` but following is not working.

```
=IF(OR(SEARCH("Sun",A:A),SEARCH("Sat",A:A)),"WeeklyOff")
```

Comment: Why are you using a range A:A  the error you're getting is likely due to the 2nd search in the or condition.`=IF(OR(A="Sun",A="Sat"),"WeeklyOff","")`

Comment: @xqbert you need to make the A and actual cell address.  leaving it as A causes an error.  Additionally that check would only be true if the entire contents of the cell matched "Sat" or "Sun".  it would fail if the cell contained XXXXXXSat2222, where as the search approach would return true (if referenced right).  The OP did specify "Within" as opposed to "equal to".  and FYI, I was thinking the same as you at first.  Then tried to figure out why op was using search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(SEARCH("Sun",A1),SEARCH("Sat",A1)),"WeeklyOff","")
```

Normally you would place this in B1 and copy down.  However if you did this you would get a series of errors.  The problem is when either search fails to located the text they are searching for, it generates an error.  To avoid this, you need to wrap your search in an error catcher like IFERROR and set it to return 0 if there is an error.

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("Sun",A1),0),IFERROR(SEARCH("Sat",A1),0)),"WeeklyOff","")
```

Now technically speaking search is going to tell you the start location of what you are looking for within the string.  so if you have "xxxxSat2" the search For "Sat"  is going to tell you 4.  Luckily the logical part of the if statement seems to take any positive integer as true.  The above formula will work as is.  I probably would have changed it to the following:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sun",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sat",A1))),"WeeklyOff","")
```

Alternatively if you column A is actually an excel date but the cells are formatted to only display the day of the week, you could use the following:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A1)=1,WEEKDAY(A1)=7),"WeeklyOff","")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the OR syntax you are using but there are two other issues with the formula you are using:

1. You need to use cell and not range, replace `A:A` with a valid referential cell location.
2. In case you date is derived from a formula, you need to first convert it into text before you use it.

Following is an example:

```
=IF(OR(SEARCH("Sun",TEXT($A1,"[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")),SEARCH("Sat",TEXT($A1,"[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"))),"WeeklyOff")
```